# Aparecer o after após o hover

Tags: html, css, css3

Estou com uma duvida, estou desenvolvendo um site com base em um layout em PSD e no menu principal, ele tem um hover que faz um sublinhado meio que personalizado: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu pensei em colocar como after e quando eu fizesse o hover, ele iria aparecer, mas estou tendo dificuldades nisso, nao sei se é a melhor solução também.

Alguma dica de como resolver?

Comment: Tente assim: `.classe:hover::before { // aqui o seu estilo }`

Comment: A sua dúvida é sobre o sublinhado no texto?

Comment: @DouglasGarrido Deu certo, Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: @WillianTártaro vou postar como resposta então. Só marcar como correta.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz esse experimento. Você pode tentar algo parecido.

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

a:hover::after {
  content: "";
  width: 150px;
  height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(147, 147, 147, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="#">A STARMILK</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte estilo no seu CSS:

```
.classe:hover::before {
    // aqui vai o seu estilo
}
```